# Disable AutoRun feature - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, autorun, windows-10-v1909

Since the key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` doesn't exist anymore. How can I modify the AutoRun value?

Additional info: Windows 10 Education - Version 1909(OS Build 18363.720)

Comment: Did you look in HKLM?  Did you look in HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Command Processor? (the 32 bit version)

Comment: yes, I found it! but the "AutoRun" value is not there. I can't be sure if it was deleted or something else. damnit windows

Comment: Hey!  Not sure about the education version.. but are you able to run [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)?  (from System Internals/MS).. It will show you EVERYTHING having to do with this sort of thing..

Answer (score 0):

If you mean autorun is the autorun.inf file which automatically runs something when plugging USB drives, then you can turn it off from Settings.

Enabling or disabling AutoPlay

To allow or prevent removable media or devices from launching automatically on Windows 10, use these steps:

- Open Settings.
- Click on Devices.
- Click on AutoPlay.

Turn on or off the Use AutoPlay for all media and devices toggle switch.

Once you complete the steps, AutoPlay on Windows 10 will be enabled or disabled depending on your configuration.

Comment: no, I meant "AutoRun", having Command Processor as parent.